# How to determine defect charge state degeneracies?

Tags: software, defects, sc-fermi

I am doing [defect calculations using the SC-FERMI package](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0010465519302048). However, one of the inputs is the degeneracy of the charge states of each defect. **I know degeneracy is the number of states with the same energy, but am unsure how to use that to determine the degeneracy of defect charge states.**

I checked the literature in which SC-FERMI is used (i.e., [this paper](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlepdf/2021/cp/d1cp02794h)), but it does not explain how this value is obtained. Thanks!

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but just came today to check how things are going? Did you figure out the answer? Are you still working on this? Let us know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the method in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.83.245207) and [this paper](https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/2014/cp/c4cp02870h) and it worked well:

To summarize:

1. The defect degeneracy level (the total # of charge carriers created by the defect) should be determined.
2. Combinatorics can be used to calculate the charge state degeneracy based on the charge state of the defect of interest.